# How to retrieve my module settings (those defined in hook_settings_form)

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to validate a request in my custom payment method module for Drupal Commerce and i need to retrieve a value that was set by the user in the admin panel, how can i do that?

I basically need a way to get back the settings defined in the implementation of `hook_settings_form()`

EDIT - this is where i define the settings for my payment method

```
/**
 * Payment method callback: settings form.
 */
function commerce_xpay_settings_form($settings = NULL) {
  $form = array();

  // Merge default settings into the stored settings array.
  $default_currency = variable_get('commerce_default_currency', 'USD');
  $xpay_languages = array(
    'ITA' => t('Italian'),
    'ENG' => t('English'),
    // '3' => t('Espagnol'),
    // '4' => t('Francaais'),
    // '5' => t('Deutsch'),
  );
  $xpay_currencies = array(
    // '1' => 'USD (US Dollar $)',
    // '2' => 'GBP (Pound Sterling ¬£)',
    // '71' => 'JPY (Japanese Yen)',
    // '71' => 'HKD (Hong Kong Dollar)',
    '978' => 'EUR (Euro ‚€)',
    // '234' => 'BRL Real',
  );

  $currency = in_array($default_currency, array_keys($xpay_currencies)) ? $default_currency : '978';
  /* The hardcoded values for commerce_xpay_tid and commerce_xpay_mac are the
   * standard values for the
   * test server, keep them while testing, documentation for x-pay is horrible */
  $settings = (array) $settings + array(
    'commerce_xpay_tid' => 'T04_000000000005',
    'commerce_xpay_mac' => 'AA88CCEWDKLSDJD3921ZZ',
    'commerce_xpay_mode' => 'TEST',
    'commerce_xpay_action_code' => 'VERI',
    'commerce_xpay_language' => 'ITA',
    'commerce_xpay_currency' => $currency,
    'commerce_xpay_method_title' => t('Credit card on a secure server:'),
    'commerce_xpay_method_title_icons' => TRUE,
    'commerce_xpay_checkout_button' => t('Submit Order'),
  );

  $form['commerce_xpay_tid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Terminal ID'),
    '#description' => t('Your Xpay teminal id.'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_tid'],
    '#size' => 25,
  );

  $form['commerce_xpay_mac'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Mac Key'),
    '#description' => t('Your MAC key'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_mac'],
    '#size' => 25,
  );

  $form['commerce_xpay_mode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Mode'),
    '#description' => t('Select NORMAL form normal usage or TEST for testing pourposes'),
    '#options' => array(
      'test' => t('TEST'),
      'normal' => t('NORMAL'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_mode'],
  );

  $form['commerce_xpay_action_code'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Action Code'),
    '#description' => t('Select the action code for the authorization request; from 21-02-2011 it has to be "VERI"'),
    '#options' => array(
      'VERI' => "VERI",
      'AUT' => "AUT",
    ),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_action_code'],
  );

  $form['commerce_xpay_language'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Language preference'),
    '#description' => t('Adjust language on XPAY pages.'),
    '#options' =>$xpay_languages,
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_language'],
  );


  $form['commerce_xpay_currency'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Currency preference'),
    '#description' => t('Adjust currency used with XPAY.'),
    '#options' => $xpay_currencies,
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_currency'],
  );


  $form['commerce_xpay_method_title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Payment method title'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_method_title'],
  );
  $form['commerce_xpay_method_title_icons'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Show credit card icons beside the payment method title.'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_method_title_icons'],
  );
  $form['commerce_xpay_checkout_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Order review submit button text'),
    '#description' => t('Provide XPAY specific text for the submit button on the order review page.'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['commerce_xpay_checkout_button'],
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: most admin settings are stored with variable_set() and retrieved with variable_get()...is that what you are after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings are available in `$payment_method['settings']`. The `$payment_method` variable is passed to almost all commerce payment hooks.